# Marking non-flat containers with responseContainer Swagger annotation attribute

Tags: java, rest, swagger

With `swagger-annotations_2.9.1` I was using following

```
 @Path("/{triggerId}/conditions")
 @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
 @ApiOperation(value = "Get a map with all conditions id an specific trigger.",
       responseClass = "Collection<Map<String, String>>",
       notes = "This is a helper for the UI to get all id of the conditions with specific type. It returns a 
       collection of {conditionId: \"value\", className: \"value\" }")
 public void getTriggerConditions(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response, ...)
```

However, in `2.10` the `responseClass` attribute is not there anymore and I guess `responseContainer` and `response` should be used instead. But how can I mark non-flat containers (List of Sets of Maps, etc.)

Actually, I am not sure how to annotate simple `Map<Foo, Bar>` with only `responseContainer` and `response`

```
    responseContainer = "Map",
    response = Foo.class,
```

and what about `Bar.class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.9.1 and 2.10 are *not* versions of swagger-core but rather versions of Scala that are used to compile the code (since older versions of swagger-core were written with Scala).

*None* of these versions support maps as containers as that was not supported by the Swagger Specification at all at that time.

If you do wish to document an operation as returning a map, you have to upgrade to the 1.5.X versions. The current version at the time of writing this comment is 1.5.0-M2.